# ITwin Briefcase lock error when trying to save changes

Tags: imodeljs, bentley-itwin

When trying to modify an imodel with

```
await iModel.concurrencyControl.locks.lockSchema(ctx);
await iModel.importSchemas(ctx, [schemaFile]);
iModel.saveChanges();
```

I get the following error:

> 409 - Lock(s) is owned by another briefcase.

I tried to abandon any changes made locally with following code:

```
const briefcaseProps = await BriefcaseManager.downloadBriefcase(
    ctx, {
    contextId,
    iModelId,
    asOf: IModelVersion.latest().toJSON()
});

// Open iModel
const iModel = await BriefcaseDb.open(ctx, {
    fileName: briefcaseProps.fileName,
    readonly: false
});
ctx.enter();
iModel.abandonChanges();
iModel.concurrencyControl.abandonResources(ctx);
```

How do you release locks owned by others briefcases ?

I am using a backend service application with nodejs based on the agent starter repo (https://github.com/iTwin/agent-starter)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is for the briefcase that created the changes to abandon or push the changes. If you know the briefcase id, you can set that when you download the briefcase. (see RequestNewBriefcaseProps argument to BriefcaseManager.downloadBriefcase), and then call your code to abandon the changes.

If the briefcase is locked by a different user, you can also consider using the project page to release the locks - connect.bentley.com -> sign in -> navigate to project -> iModel Manager -> Pick iModel -> Settings Icon (the gear on the top right) -> Manage Resources.

Comment: I don't have the 'Manage Resources' button on the settings icon, but I manage to download the briefcase with a briefcase id and abandon changes. Thanks a lot